# Rewrite an Answered Question?

Tags: discussion

So I just asked the following question based on an incorrect assumption:

[Temp Table Clustered Key Not Being Honored: Bug or Expected Functionality?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/177032/temp-table-clustered-key-not-being-honored-bug-or-expected-functionality)

Martin Smith provided a great answer on why I was seeing my behavior, but his answer was to the eventual follow-up question I asked after some back and forth with the comment sections.

My question for here: is there a point where I adjust the question to fit the eventual accepted answer?  I don't mind looking like a dummy for asking a bad question, but the answer I accepted is for the follow-up question and not the question in its primary form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, for the specific question, I don't think you need to change anything. Your original question basically was (the title hasn't changed):

> Temp Table Clustered Key Not Being Honored: Bug or Expected Functionality?

The answer by @Martin Smith answers your original question by addressing your (false) assumption about the behaviour of queries without `ORDER BY`.

I don't see any problem with keeping the question as it is, including the edit with the clarifications / assumptions.